# Show that $ \hat{\theta}_2 = Y_{(n)} - \frac{n}{n+1}$ is unbiased estimators of $θ$.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

Let $Y_1$, $Y_2$, . . . , $Y_n$ denote a random sample from the uniform distribution on the interval $(θ, θ + 1)$. Let $$ \hat{\theta}_2 = Y_{(n)} - \frac{n}{n+1}$$

Show that $\hat{\theta}_2$ is unbiased estimators of $θ$.

I am told that the density of $\hat{\theta}_2 = Y_{(n)}: g_n(y) = n(y-\theta)^{n-1}, \theta \le y \le \theta +1$. My question is how to find these?

Then, the second part of the solution is $E(\hat{\theta}_2) = E(Y_{(n)}) - \frac{n}{n+1} = \theta$...

However, how does this follow from the previous answer?

Also, I try to compare the efficiency of $θ^1$ relative to $θ^2$... I am wondering how to find the $\text Var [\hat{\theta}_2]$ which I am told that $\text Var [\hat{\theta}_2]= V(Y_{(n)})=\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}$ I am wondering how they calculate $\text Var [\hat{\theta}_2]$?

$$E(Y_{(n)}^2) = ny^2(y-\theta)^{n-1} = n\left[\left.y^2\frac{(y-\theta)^n}{n} \right|_\theta^{\theta+1} - \frac{2}{n} \int_\theta^{\theta+1} y(y-\theta)^n  \,dy\right]$$

$$= \left.(\theta+1)^2 - 2\left(y\frac{(y-\theta)^{n+1}}{n+1} \right|_\theta^{\theta+1} - \int_\theta^{\theta+1} \frac{(y-\theta)^{n+1}}{n+1} dy\right) = (\theta+1)^2 -2 \left(\frac{\theta+1}{n+1} - \left.\frac{(y-\theta)^{n+2}}{(n+1)(n+2)}\right|_\theta^{\theta+1}\right)$$

$$= (\theta+1)^2- 2\frac{\theta +1}{n+1} - \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$$

I check the Latex for the middle two lines... I could not figure out what went wrong please focus on my answer ...If I use $E(Y_{(n)}^2)$ - $E(Y_{(n)})^2$, based on wolframalpha which gives me the following result ...please go to the link https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28x%2B1%29%5E2-2%28%28x%2B1%29%2F%28n%2B1%29%29+%2B+1%2F%28%28n%2B1%29%28n%2B2%29%29+-+%28%28x%2B1%29+-+1%2F%28n%2B1%29%29%5E2 ...which is different from the correct answer $\text Var [\hat{\theta}_2]= V(Y_{(n)})=\frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}$....Could anyone please check why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $Y_i\sim\mathcal{U}(\theta,\theta+1)$ and CDF of $Y_i$ based on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_(continuous))
$$
G_{Y_i}(y)=\Pr[Y_i\le y]=\frac{y-\theta}{\theta+1-\theta}=y-\theta.
$$
Here, $Y_{(n)}$ is $n$-th order statistics. Therefore, $Y_{(n)}=\max[Y_1,\cdots, Y_n]$. Note that $Y_{(n)}\le y$ equivalence to $Y_i\le y$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,n$. Hence, for $\theta< y<\theta+1$, the fact that $Y_1,Y_2,\cdots, Y_n$ are **i.i.d.** implies
$$
G_{Y_{(n)}}(y)=\Pr[Y_{(n)}\le y]=\Pr[Y_1\le y,Y_2\le y,\cdots, Y_n\le y]=(\Pr[Y_i\le y])^n=\left(y-\theta\right)^{n}.
$$
The PDF of $Y_{(n)}$ is
$$
g_{Y_{(n)}}(y)=\frac{d}{dy}G_{Y_{(n)}}(y)=\frac{d}{dy}(y-\theta)^n=n(y-\theta)^{n-1}.
$$
The expected value of $Y_{(n)}$ is
$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]&=\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}yg_{Y_{(n)}}(y)\ dy\\
&=\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}yn(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy\\
&=n\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}y(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy.
\end{align}
$$
Integral above can be solved by using IBP or integration by reduction formula (you may refer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/253032/reduction-formula-i-m-n-int-xmxandx)).
$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]&=n\left[\frac{y(y-\theta)^n}{n+1}-\frac{\theta(y-\theta)^n}{n(n+1)}\right]_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}\\
&=\frac{n(\theta+1)}{n+1}+\frac{\theta}{n+1}\\
&=\theta+\frac{n}{n+1}.
\end{align}
$$

---

**ADDENDUM :**

Using IBP, let $u=y\Rightarrow du=dy$ and $dv=(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy\Rightarrow v=\dfrac{(y-\theta)^n}{n}$. Hence
$$
\begin{align}
n\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}y(y-\theta)^{n-1}\ dy&=n\left[\left.\dfrac{y(y-\theta)^n}{n}\right|_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}-\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}\dfrac{(y-\theta)^n}{n} dy\right]\\
&=(\theta+1)-\int_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}(y-\theta)^{n}\ dy\\
&=(\theta+1)-\left.\dfrac{(y-\theta)^{n+1}}{n+1}\right|_{y=\theta}^{\theta+1}\\
&=(\theta+1)-\dfrac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}
$$

Variance can be evaluated as follows
$$
\text{Var}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}-\frac{n}{n+1}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]=\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}^2\right]-\left(\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]\right)^2.
$$
Since the term $\dfrac{n}{n+1}$ is a constant, then you can ignore it. Variance is invariant with respect to changes in a location parameter. That is, if a constant is added to all values of the variable, the variance is unchanged. You may refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties) to learn properties of variance.

---

Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\text{E}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]&=\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}-\frac{n}{n+1}\right]\\
&=\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]-\frac{n}{n+1}\\
&=\theta+\frac{n}{n+1}-\frac{n}{n+1}\\
&=\theta.
\end{align}
$$
Since $\text{E}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]=\theta$, we can conclude that $\hat{\theta}_{2}$ is **unbiased** estimator of $\theta$.

$$\\$$

---

$$\Large\color{blue}{\text{# }\mathbb{Q.E.D.}\text{ #}}$$

Comment: Could you show me how to use IBP to solve $\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]$?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Let $u=y$ and $dv=(y-\theta)^{n-1}$, then you will get $du=dy$ and $v=\dfrac{(y-\theta)^{n}}{n}$.

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Done!

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have one more related question: I try to compare the efficiency of $\hat{\theta_1}$ relative to $\hat{\theta_2}$... I am wondering how to find the $V(\hat{\theta_2})$ which I am told that $V(\hat{\theta_2}) = V(Y_{(n)}) = \frac{n}{(n+2)(n+1)^2}$ I am wondering how they calculate $V(\hat{\theta_2})$?

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf Variance can be evaluated as follows 
$$
\text{Var}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}-\frac{n}{n+1}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}\right].
$$
Since the term $\dfrac{n}{n+1}$ is a constant, then you can ignore it. You may refer [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Properties) to learn properties of variance.

Comment: could you revise it a little bit since it is unreadable now?

Comment: $$
\text{Var}\left[\hat{\theta}_{2}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}-\frac{n}{n+1}\right]=\text{Var}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]=\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}^2\right]-\left(\text{E}\left[Y_{(n)}\right]\right)^2
$$

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf I don't know what is wrong with my LaTeX code. you can copy my last LaTeX code to your **ask question editor**. It's readable there.

Comment: could you repaste that under your answer as I am going to change my question at the same time?

Comment: I cannot copy your last latex since some of the text are missing

Comment: I've copied my comment to my answer since an hour ago. Now you can check it. It's already clear enough and it's should be easy to obtain the variance. You can do it by yourself.

Comment: Based your comment, I tried to calculate the $E(Y_{(n)}^2)$...However, I cannot find the correct answer please take a look of my revised questions

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf I just don't get it, what exactly are you asking? Is it $\text{Var}[\hat{\theta}_{2}]$ or $\text{Var}[\theta^{2}]$?

Comment: should be $\text Var [\hat{\theta}_2]$

Comment: @afsdfdfsaf How come I help you if you didn't accept yet this answer? Why you don't ask another question but this time only asking $\text Var [\hat{\theta}_2]$? Maybe other members will help you. I don't wanna edit this answer again. It's already full. If no one help you, I'll try to answer it tomorrow. At this time I couldn't help you. I'm not in home.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $Y_{(n)}=\max\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n\}$. Given i.i.d. observations the cdf of $Y_{(n)}$ is given by
$$
G_{Y_{(n)}}(y)=\mathsf{P}(\max\{Y_1,Y_2,...,Y_n\}\le y)=[G_{Y}(y)]^n=(y-\theta)^n,
$$
and the density of $Y_{(n)}$ is
$$
g_{Y_{(n)}}(y)=\frac{d}{dy}[G_{Y}(y)]^n=n(y-\theta)^{n-1}.
$$

Thus,
\begin{align}
\mathsf{E}[\hat{\theta}_2]& = \int_\theta^{\theta+1}yn(y-\theta)^{n-1}dy-\frac{n}{n+1} \\
&=\frac{\theta(n+1)+n}{n+1}-\frac{n}{n+1}=\theta.
\end{align}