# General formula for $\int_a^b(x-a)^m(x-b)^ndx$

Tags: integration, reduction-formula

Recently, I stumbled upon this:

> $$\int_a^b (x-a)^3(x-b)^4dx$$

I did this in many ways - using IBP multiple times and by even expanding both terms like a madman.

The result was: $$\frac{(a-b)^8}{280}$$
I was astonished by this cute little result. So I started wondering about evaluating the following:

$$\int_a^b(x-a)^m(x-b)^ndx$$

I wanted to use reduction to obtain a result similar to [Wallis' formula for sine and cosine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis%27_integrals)

---

Any other method is always welcome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start using IBP:

$$I_{(m,n)}=\int_a^b(x-a)^m(x-b)^ndx=0-\int_a^b m(x-a)^{m-1}\frac{(x-b)^{n+1}}{n+1}dx=-\frac{m}{n+1}I_{(m-1,n+1)}$$

Applying IBP multiple times, we obtain $$I_{(m,n)}=(-1)^{m+1}\frac{m!.n!}{(n+m)!}I_{(0,n+m)}$$

$$\boxed{I_{(m,n)}=(-1)^{m+1}\frac{m!.n!}{(n+m+1)!}(a-b)^{n+m+1}}$$

Comment: I think you got the sign wrong. Take for example in the question $a=0$, $b=1$. So the integral of $x^3(x-1)^4$ should be positive. For $m=3$ and $n=4$ your result is negative.

Comment: @Andrei thank you for pointing it out. I hope its fixed now.

Comment: Your second line was right before, but you got the limits on the integral in reverse order. $I_{(0,n+m)}=\int_a^b(x-b)^{n+m}dx=\int_{a-b}^0u^{n+m}du=-(a-b)^{n+m+1}/(n+m+1)$

Comment: Oh yes I got it, thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Let $u=(x-a)/(b-a)$ so that
\begin{align}
\int_a^b(x-a)^m(x-b)^ndx=(-1)^m(b-a)^{m+n+1}\int_0^1u^m\left(1-u\right)^ndx
\end{align}
and latter integral is a well-known quantity.

Comment: Is the latter integral related to beta/gamma functions? I don't know much about them.

Comment: You are right: this is the beta function.

Answer (score 0):

I liked your method the best.But if you are fine with using wallis formula,here is a hint;

**Hint** use the substituition $$x=a+({b-a})\sin^2 \theta$$
$$dx=2(b-a)\sin \theta \cos \theta d\theta$$

can you take it from here?